# I want to show column status ex.if day left has 30 days status it danger

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want status to have a relation with `day_left`, e.g. if `day_left` has 30 days `status` should be `danger`. This is homework

```html
<?php
$con2= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","database") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con2)); 
 
$query2 = "SELECT *,datediff (mainexpire,now())   as day_left  from contact";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con2, $query2);






echo "<table border='1'  align='center' width='1000'>";




echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFACD'><td><p><center><b>no</center></td></p></b><td><p><center><b>maintenance items 
</center></td></p></b><td><p><center><b>owner
</td></p></center></b>
<td><p><center><b>detail
</center></td></p></b><td><p><center><b>expire_date
</center></td></p></b><td><p><center><b>Days Left
</center></td></p></b><td><p><center><b>Status
</center></td></p></b>     
</tr>";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["no"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["mainitem"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["mainowner"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["maindetail"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["mainexpire"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
echo "<td><center><p>" .$row2["day_left"] .  "</center></td></p> ";
}
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are doing good with that homework (if you did that of your own, of course). Just need to add a `if else` condition for the `status`. Some thing like this after the last line of your `while` loop.

```
if( $row2["day_left"] > 30 ) { 
    echo "<td><center><p>All OK</center></td></p> "; 
} else { 
    echo "<td><center><p>Danger</center></td></p> "; 
}
```

Comment: All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function day_left($day){ //$day will be the target date
 $target_date= strtotime($day);  //this convert the target day to second
 $today = strtotime("today"); //this convert the current day to second
   $day_sec = $target_date- $today; //so target day minus current day second
   $total_day_left = $day_sec / 86400; //divide it to 86400 thats equivalent to one day
    return $total_day_left; //the total day left
}
```

Comment: i create function day_left, the parameters accept the target date. then convert it all in second with (strtotime). its just simply return how many days left

Comment: please add in your answer not in comment line